# Resolving Express error: "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:652:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\kambl\OneDrive\Desktop\ApnaCollege\mYSQL\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:795:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (C:\Users\kambl\OneDrive\Desktop\ApnaCollege\mYSQL\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:625:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\kambl\OneDrive\Desktop\ApnaCollege\mYSQL\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:150:14)  
    at done (C:\Users\kambl\OneDrive\Desktop\ApnaCollege\mYSQL\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1053:10)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\kambl\OneDrive\Desktop\ApnaCollege\mYSQL\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:280:5)
    at exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\kambl\OneDrive\Desktop\ApnaCollege\mYSQL\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\kambl\OneDrive\Desktop\ApnaCollege\mYSQL\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\kambl\OneDrive\Desktop\ApnaCollege\mYSQL\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\kambl\OneDrive\Desktop\ApnaCollege\mYSQL\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
```

I am currently learning so haven't been able to resolve this error. This is my code:

```
const { faker } = require('@faker-js/faker');
const mysql=require("mysql2");
const express= require( "express" );
const app=express();
const path=require("path");

app.set( 'view engine', 'ejs' );
app.set("views",path.join(__dirname,"/views"));

const connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    database:"delta_app",
    password:"Arbitron12#7006"
});

let getRandomUser=()=>{
    return [
            faker.string.uuid(),
            faker.internet.userName(),
            faker.internet.email(),
            faker.internet.password()
        ];
    };
//Home route
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    let q=`SELECT count(*) FROM temp`
    try{
    connection.query(q,(err,result)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        let count=result[0]["count(*)"]
        res.render("Home.ejs",{count})
    });
    } catch (err){
    console.log(err);
    res.send("Some error in DB")
    }
});

//Show route
app.get("/user",(req,res)=>{
    let q= `select * from temp`;
    try{
        connection.query(q,(err,users)=>{
            if(err)throw err;
            res.render("showusers.ejs",{ users });
        });
        } catch (err){
        console.log(err);
        res.send("Some error in DB");
        }
    res.send("success");
});
app.listen("8080",() => {
    console.log("Server is listening to the port 8080");
});
```

Comment: Your "show route" does `res.render` (asynchronously) after `res.send`, which means _two_ responses to one request. This is forbidden and leads to the error that you observe.